# DB2: how to resolve decfloat error for decimal column?

Tags: db2

While trying to run below query am getting decfloat error. As per the ddl of DX.FACT_RULES table revenue is decimal(18,2)

SELECT
REVENUE
FROM DX.FACT_RULES

Please help me with solution.

I have tried to change as CAST(REVENUE as DECFLOAT(32)) and also CAST(DECFLOAT(REVENUE) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) still no use

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: You can’t get such an error on `REVENUE` of `DECIMAL` data type. Is it really of some string data type? Please, provide some fully reproducible example with `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO` and real `SELECT` using this table.

Answer (score 1):

Likley you are getting this error

```
db2 "values '£101' * 1"

1                                         
------------------------------------------
SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the 
function "DECFLOAT".  SQLSTATE=22018
```

which you get when treating a string as a number, but the string can't be cast to a number (a DECFLOAT in this case)

You need to find the values that can't be converted to a number. A function such as this can be used to find such values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_IS_DECFLOAT(i VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS INTEGER
    CONTAINS SQL ALLOW PARALLEL 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE NOT_VALID CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22018';
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT_VALID RETURN 0;

  RETURN CASE WHEN CAST(i AS DECFLOAT) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END;
END
```

e.g.

```
SELECT v
FROM TABLE(VALUES ('£123'),(' +123.45 ')) as t(V)
WHERE DB_IS_DECFLOAT(v) = 0
```

which would return

```
V   
----
£123
```

Comment: how do I find the culprit value?

Comment: am just getting error " Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.21.31"

Comment: You can use my `DB_IS_DECFLOAT` function above to find the culprit value. It returns a 0 when the string can't be converted to a decfloat.  If DX.FACT_RULES is a view, you would need to look as the SQL that defines the view to see where you have a string column geting treated as a number